# Combining MEDIAN IF Array with Indirect

Tags: excel-formula

I'd like to add an additional condition that uses INDIRECT to the following array that currently works:

`=MEDIAN(IF(Signals!$B3:$AOT3=0,IF(Signals!$B3:$AOT3<>"",IF(Signals!$DUI3:$FKA3<>"",Signals!$DUI3:$FKA3))))`

Here is the formula I've tried with the additional condition, which I added to the beginning:

`=MEDIAN(IF(INDIRECT("Signals!$B"&$Z$2&":$AOT"&$Z$2&"="&$Z$3),IF(Signals!$B3:$AOT3=0,IF(Signals!$B3:$AOT3<>"",IF(Signals!$DUI3:$FKA3<>"",Signals!$DUI3:$FKA3)))))`

$Z$2 currently contains the value of 5, and $Z$3 contains 0.

The attempt above results in #REF!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to use `INDIRECT` on the cell address, not the equal sign. Try instead

```
=MEDIAN(IF(
INDIRECT("Signals!$B"&$Z$2&":$AOT"&$Z$2)=&$Z$3),
IF(Signals!$B3:$AOT3=0,
IF(Signals!$B3:$AOT3<>"",
IF(Signals!$DUI3:$FKA3<>"",Signals!$DUI3:$FKA3)))))
```

As a side note, I am not understanding that `IF` statement, I would double check if it's actually doing what you want.